# How can I use Celery in Django with just the DB?

Tags: python, django, celery

Looking at https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/v5.2.7/getting-started/backends-and-brokers/index.html it sounds pretty much as if it's not possible / desirable. There is a section about SQLAlchemy, but Django does not use SQLAlchemy.

In way older docs, there is https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/3.1/getting-started/brokers/django.html .

Is it possible with recent Celery / Django versions to use Celery with just the database for storing messages / results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can totally do this, even if it's not the most performant/recommended way to do. I use it for simple projects in which I don't want to add Redis.

To do so, first, add SQLAlchemy v1 as a dependency in your project: `SQLAlchemy = "1.*"`

Then in your settings.py:

- if you use PostgreSQL: `CELERY_BROKER_URL = sqla+postgresql://user:pwd@127.0.0.1:5432/dbname`
- if you use SQLite: `CELERY_BROKER_URL = "sqla+sqlite:///" + os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'your_database.db')` . Note that the folder holding the database must be writable. For example if your database is located in `project/dbfolder/database.db`, `chmod 777 project/dbfolder` will do the trick.

As a sidenote, I'm using [django-celery-results](https://django-celery-results.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to store results of my tasks. This way, I have a fully featured Celery without using other tech tool (like rabbitMQ or Redis) in my stack.

Comment: Being available in 3.1 docs only doesnt make me feel very confident. But, indeed it is still there: https://github.com/celery/kombu/tree/main/kombu/transport - and with it, a few more, like filesystem or memory. It seems that celery really only mentions officially supported brokers, in it's docs.

Comment: How is your experience about performance, task executed twice, and the like? I guess it could work very well, with low volume?

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use a relational SQL database as a broker, SQLAlchemy indeed is your best option, since it's supported by Celery already. I would be careful about this approach though, because not only you're (ab)using a relational database as a message broker, but also the Celery docs recommend caution:

> Historically, SQLAlchemy has not been the most stable result backend
> so if chosen one should proceed with caution.

Django does not use SQLAlchemy indeed, because it has it's own ORM, but that's not preventing you from using SQLAlchemy in the Celery worker.

Comment: What you quote from the docs is about the SQLAlchemy "Result Backend". It doesn't even mention SQLAlchemy as a broker... ;-)